# Use parameters in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm actually a student and I'm working on a small project that is roughly finished except that I'm stuck with one form who displays activities. Every time user is selecting an activity I would like the activity already filled up but actually, it is always locked with the first activity provided from the form ( Only Url is good but nothing is happening on the form).

I don't if it's writing in the " good way" but my form is like this (_form.html.erb) :

```
<%= form_with(model: activity, local: true) do |form| %>
     <% if activity.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(activity.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this activity from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% activity.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>



  <div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :activities, class:'activity_title' %>
  <%= form.select :activities, options_for_select(['Running', 'Fitness', 'Rugby', 'Crossfit', 'Track&Field', 'Walk', 'Volleyball', 'Football', 'Basketball', 'Swimming', 'Dancing','Handball']),  {:params => @activity.activities},  class: 'form-control'  %>
</div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :duration , class:'duration_title' %>
    <%= form.number_field :duration %>
  </div>

  <div class="fielddate">
    <%= form.label :date , class:'date_title' %>
    <%= form.datetime_select :date %>
  </div>
```

And i have big doubt with this parameter, especialy with {:params => @activity.activities}:

```
  <div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :activities, class:'activity_title' %>
  <%= form.select :activities, options_for_select(['Running', 'Fitness', 'Rugby', 'Crossfit', 'Track&Field', 'Walk', 'Volleyball', 'Football', 'Basketball', 'Swimming', 'Dancing','Handball']),  {:params => @activity.activities},  class: 'form-control'  %>
</div>
```

activities_controller.rb:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_activity, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user! 

  # GET /activities
  # GET /activities.json
  def index
    @activities = current_user.activities
  end

  # GET /activities/1
  # GET /activities/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /activities/new
  def new
  
    @activity = Activity.new(:activities => params[:activities])
    puts @activity.activities

  end

  # GET /activities/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /activities
  # POST /activities.json
  def create
    @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
    @activity.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @activity.save
        format.html { redirect_to activities_url, notice: 'Activity was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @activity }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /activities/1
  # PATCH/PUT /activities/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @activity.update(activity_params)
        format.html { redirect_to activities_url, notice: 'Activity was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @activity }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /activities/1
  # DELETE /activities/1.json
  def destroy
    @activity.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to activities_url, notice: 'Activity was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_activity
      @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def activity_params
      params.require(:activity).permit(:activities, :duration, :date)
    end
end
```

[image]

If you have any solution to share it I will be very happy! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I find the solution myself, it was necessary to remove all activity name and replace it with @activity.activities

```
   <div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :activities, class:'activity_title' %>
  <%= form.select :activities, options_for_select([ @activity.activities ])  %>
</div>
```